# How to submit multiple partial Forms within a Form with one button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have multiple views and render all of them within another view.
Now, after the user did his input, I want to submit all of the 4 views with one button click.

I googled a lot, but all the things I've found so far are the exact opposite of what I want to do (submit multiple forms separately).

Here is what I have now:

```
@using Kunden.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

    <h2>Index</h2>
    <div class="row">
```

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Firma", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "firma" })){
            @RenderPage("~/Views/Firma/Create.cshtml")
        }
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Adresse", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "adresse" }))
        {
            @RenderPage("~/Views/Adresse/Create.cshtml")
        }
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Person", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "person" }))
        {
            @RenderPage("~/Views/Person/Create.cshtml")
        }
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Kontodaten", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "kontodaten" }))
        {
            @RenderPage("~/Views/Kontodaten/Create.cshtml")
        }

    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" name="commandName" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" 
               onclick="document.getElementById('adresse').submit();
                        document.getElementById('person').submit();
                        document.getElementById('kontodaten').submit();
                        document.getElementById('firma').submit();
                         " />
    </div>
</div>
```

My requests are like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Person person)
        {
            phentitis.Person.Add(person);
            phentitis.SaveChanges();

            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

I want all the Data to be saved, but only one submit passes through (and it's the third one?! That's really confusing for me)

Comment: I would remove the onclick attribute in your submit button, add a jQuery event for form submit either on the class or give it an id, serialize all four forms for your data value, and then submit via an ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```html
<input type="button" value="Create" onclick="submitForms();" />
```

```js
<script>

    // Submit multiple forms
    function submitForms()
    {
        submitForm(document.getElementById('adresse'));
        submitForm(document.getElementById('person'));
        submitForm(document.getElementById('kontodaten'));
        submitForm(document.getElementById('firma'));

    } // End of the submitForms method

    // Submit a form
    function submitForm(form) {

        // Disable buttons
        disableButtons();

        // Get form data
        var fd = new FormData(form);

        // Post form data
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', form.getAttribute('action'), true);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                // Get the response
                var data = JSON.parse(xhr.response);

                // Check the success status
                if (data.success === true) {
                    // Check if we should redirect the user or show a message
                    if (data.url !== null && data.url !== '') {
                        // Redirect the user
                        location.href = data.url;
                    }
                    else {
                        // Output a success message
                        annytab.notifier.show('success', data.message);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // Output error information
                    annytab.notifier.show('error', data.message);
                }
            }
            else {
                // Output error information
                annytab.notifier.show('error', xhr.status + " - " + xhr.statusText);
            }

            // Enable buttons
            enableButtons();

        };
        xhr.onerror = function () {
            // Output error information
            annytab.notifier.show('error', xhr.status + " - " + xhr.statusText);

            // Enable buttons
            enableButtons();
        };
        xhr.send(fd);

    } // End of the submitForm method

</script>
```

```c#
public class ResponseData
{
    #region variables

    public bool success { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public ResponseData()
    {
        // Set values for instance variables
        this.success = false;
        this.id = "";
        this.message = "";
        this.url = "";

    } // End of the constructor

    public ResponseData(bool success, string id, string message, string url = "")
    {
        // Set values for instance variables
        this.success = success;
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
        this.url = url;

    } // End of the constructor

    #endregion

    #region Get methods

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);

    } // End of the ToString method

    #endregion

} // End of the class
```

```c#
// Return a success response
return Json(data: new ResponseData(true, "", "Everyting was perfect"));
```

Comment: I tried that, but it's redirecting me to a blank ../adresss url (first submit, that submit works btw.) and jeah, that's it. 
Do you have an idea of how to prevent that redirecting?

Comment: You can test to return something else than new EmptyResult() from your Controller method. ResponseData for example or just **return Ok();**

Comment: Thank you very much, you're a lifesaver ;-) Got it to work ;D Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need Ajax to send multiple forms, otherwise only the first submit to the server will go through. You can use Ajax to submit each form individually in a Javascript function.
First, switch your Html.BeginForms to Ajax.BeginForms, wrap them in unique divs, change your button to a Javascript function call, and then add the Javascript.

```html
@using Kunden.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div id="firmaDiv">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Firma", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "firmaDiv" }, htmlAttributes: new { id = "firma" }))
        {
            @RenderPage("~/Views/Firma/Create.cshtml")
        }
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="addresseDiv">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Adresse", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "addresseDiv" }, htmlAttributes: new { id = "addresse" }))
        {
            @RenderPage("~/Views/Adresse/Create.cshtml")
        }
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="personDiv">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Person", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "personDiv" }, htmlAttributes: new { id = "person" }))
            {
                @RenderPage("~/Views/Person/Create.cshtml")
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="kontoDiv">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Kontodaten", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "kontoDiv" }, htmlAttributes: new { id = "kontodaten" }))
            {
                @RenderPage("~/Views/Kontodaten/Create.cshtml")
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="button" name="commandName" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" onclick="submitForms()" />
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForms() {
        document.getElementById('firma').submit();
        document.getElementById('adresse').submit();
        document.getElementById('person').submit();
        document.getElementById('kontodaten').submit();
    }
</script>
```

In your controllers, after the form has been posted, return a PartialView with a success or failure message.

```
if(successful)
{
    return PartialView("Success");
}
else
{
    return PartialView("Fail");
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried that but unfortunately, it doesn't work.
If I use the submit button, I get redirected to my Index, but nothing is happening. (despite me having no redirections in the post actions?!)
Any Idea why that is? Should I share more code?
Edit: If I use the old Version with the button onclick submit stuff, it doesn't work either.

Comment: The input type should not be **submit**, use **button** when you submit from JavaScript. An input with type **submit** submits a form to the action url.

Comment: @FredrikStigsson Excellent catch there. I missed that. I've updated the input tag with a type of button instead of submit.

Comment: @user3793935 You can add an UpdateTargetId to the AjaxOptions so that any response from the server will be rendered on the current page. Give each of the divs that contain the forms a unique id and set that id as the Update target. Then, have your controller send a success/failure response in a PartialView and the page will be updated as each form is submitted.

Comment: @Stephen thank you for your effort, appreciate it.
It still won't work. 
It seems like the post request never get called. 
And the view that renders the other views has a controller too, obviously, but what I don't understand is why the create function of that controller gets called too.
I mean, there is no submit for that in the submit function?
I don't know, I think I've done something completely wrong, but I really don't know what ;-(

Comment: Another thing you might try is a single form with a ViewModel that is a combination of all four of your models (firma, person, addresse, klntodaten). Then you only need a single submit and the controller that handles the post can create each new object from the ViewModel.